# split a file in one machine and join the files in another machine

Tags: linux, join, split, apache-zookeeper, cat

I need to split a file if it is more than x bytes and join all the files in another machine. I am using the Linux utility

```
split
```

to split the files and the

```
cat
```

utility to join the files. 
*split* provides the *bytes* and the  *lines* option to split the files.
Which option is better for splitting, since I am retrieving the files in another machine and which one is a efficient way to split and join?.

There may be chance of byte loss while transferring one machine to another machine.

Comment: If you transfer the file with TCP, changes of byte loss are 0. split and cat is a proper way to do what you are telling, but probably the right attempt to your real word problem is to compress the file instead of splitting it

Comment: I couldn't compress since the file size is greater than the expected one. Also there is a possibility of storing the file contents in zookeeper too. Is there any loss of bytes or any issues?